# I want to create a column with a custom function based on another column on Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

The function searches a value in a Excel workbook and gives me a cetain info.

It Works like this:

```
Excel
Column1     Column2
A              1
B              2
C              3

My Function ("A") - Output > 1
My Function ("B") - Output > 2
My Function ("C") - Output > 3
```

Now i got a table in Power Query, like this:

```
Power Query
ColumnX

B
C
A
A
```

I want to create another column on the power query table using my function. And as input i want to use de column X.

But right now, it isn't working.

PS. the output of the function is a M Formula(Ex:. [Column10] * [Column11])

The line of code that i'm using is:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo Alterado", "Formula", each Expression.Evaluate(MyFunction([ColumnX]),#shared))
```

Already tried without de enviroment variable and it didn't work.

PS2: If i write the code as if it was only one input at columnX it works!
The code looks like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"table1", "Formula", Expression.Evaluate(MyFunction("B"),#shared))
```

Someone knows how to make it work ?

Comment: Post a copy of your function code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated

You can remove all of the Expression Evaluate calls. (The second step looks like you're passing the result of a function, but Table.AddColumn needs a function definition )

> PS. the output of the function is a M Formula(Ex:. [Column10] * [Column11])

In that case you may want to pass the row as the argument, instead of the specific column. It depends on what you're doing.

```
let
    Source = ...,
    MyFunction = (row as record) =>
        row[Column10] * row[Column11],

    #"Add Column2" = Table.AddColumn(
        Source, "Column2", 
        (row) => MyFunction( row ),
        type any // replace with the right type
    )
in
    #"Add Column2"
```

### Original Answer

I think what you're asking for is a simple mapping. You can skip the Expression.Evaluate

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    Source, "Column2", 
    (row) => 
        MyFunction( row[Column1] ),
    type any
)
```